# What is Star Wars Squadrons download size?

Tags: star-wars-squadrons

The disc space is 30 gigabytes, but the download size is always more compressed than the disc space.  Does anyone know the **download** size of star wars squadrons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this source](https://twinfinite.net/2020/10/star-wars-squadrons-download-install-size/) and [this Reddit thread:](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsSquadrons/comments/izkcc8/star_wars_squadrons_size/)

- **PS4:** 22.12 GB.
- **Xbox One:** 27.9 GB. In addition, if you have the Xbox One X, it will download additional 4K assets and the download size will be larger.
- **PC:** 23.3 GB, with 40 GB minimum required for install.

However, all of this is the vanilla game without patches, so it might change if additional patches and updates come out.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer.  I figured it would be around 20 gig.